# Is the sample Java mesher indicative of Tango's mapping capabilities

Tags: google-project-tango

I recently received my Tango device and I intend to use it to develop an application that would allow me to easily create/mesh and export 3d maps of one's environment. I have loaded the sample java mesher found on googles website to test out tangos capabilities. The mesh works but is to slow and blurry for how i intend to use it. Is this the full capability of Tango or is it just limited by the project code.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd suggest you to try PointCloud example to see how your device percepts depth and what is the level of accuracy.
2. Java Mesh Builder example is not indicative - check RTAB-Map and Constructor apps.
3. As of speed try native C/C++ examples too.